# Why cant Scipy Install on Windows 7 using easy_install and cygwin?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have tried multiple times, but never have been able to install scipy via easy_install on cygwin. I am using python 2.6.5 and Windows 7. After installing numpy successfully, I try to install scipy via the following command:

easy_install -U scipy

and see the following errors:

```
                  bnrm2,resid,info = zstoptest2(r,b,bnrm2,tol,info)
        Wrote C/API module "_iterative" to file "build/src.cygwin-1.7.9-i686-2.6/build/src.cygwin-1.7.9-i686-2.6/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative
_iterativemodule.c"
      1 [main] python 6160 C:\cygwin\bin\python.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\python2.6\lib-dynload\time.dll to same addre
s as parent: 0x320000 != 0x3F0000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
00286AF8  6102796B  (00286AF8, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
00286DE8  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
00287E18  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 61243884, 00320000, 003F0000)
End of stack trace
      2 [main] python 2232 fork: child 6160 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
error: Setup script exited with error: Resource temporarily unavailabl
```

No clue what is going on, and was not able to install this on my last PC either. Has anyone successfully installed this module using cygwin? Do i have to build from source? If so, that seems like a HUGE pain in the ass.

Thanks

e

Comment: Specifically AcivePython 2.7 which has the scipy package: http://code.activestate.com/pypm/scipy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the dreaded "rebase problem".

Install rebase and run "rebaseall" per the instructions and see if that works.

It has to do with the way that Windows maps DLLs into memory and sometimes they collide.